# Reddit API redirect_uri?

Tags: php, reddit

I want to use the Reddit REST API for PHP. I have downloaded all necessary files and have used my id and secret however I have no idea what to have as the redirect uri. Every time I try to execute the code, it goes to the reddit site and says it's an invalid redirect_uri.

What can I use as a redirect uri?

Answer (score 0):

The redirect URI is where the user is sent after they've granted OAuth access to your application.  There's more information about this in [the reddit OAuth docs](https://github.com/reddit/reddit/wiki/OAuth2).